# macOS Big Sur (Command + Tab) does not show the Finder App anymore

Tags: finder, big-sur

Pressing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between open applications works fine except it does not show me the default Finder App anymore.

I tried to reboot the laptop but still same issue. Of course if I click the Finder App directly from the Dock, the Finder Window open but still even with the Finder Window open, if I press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> I still can not see the Finder App icon among the current running applications.

This is not a managed device, is my personal laptop without any managed profiles installed.

I did not run any command line to hide anything.

[image: This is what I see when I press CMD TAB]

Answer (score 1):

Restarting in Safe Mode first and restarting again in regular mode it fixed the issue.